# Resharper Ruleset, can we share them?

Tags: resharper

I work in a small dev team and we've recently acquired Resharper. Is it possible to configure Resharper's ruleset (e.g. Disabling resharper from wanting to rename everything to "var" ) on one machine and distribute that ruleset amongst all the developers?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to disable implicit typing?  It's very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can find this in Resharper -> Options -> Languages -> Common -> Code Style Sharing.

**UPDATE**: In Resharper 6, settings management can be found in Resharper -> Manage Options... From there you can import/export settings files and apply a layered configuration.

Comment: thanks :) I had just found the answer but I'll mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: This is not necessarily what the OP wanted. In there you can only share settings "per solution", not amongst all the developers. Only the devs using that solution.

Comment: You can place the file on a network drive, mark it read only and then have everyone point to that file or they could point to a file that they have checked out of source control but cannot change. I've never liked the per solution method.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it is quite possible to share code styles (you'd have to investigate more closely what they mean under "Code Style"). See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200804062150/http://geekswithblogs.net/alternativedotnet/archive/2008/10/20/125936.aspx):

[alt text http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/alternativedotnet/WindowsLiveWriter/SharingReSharpersettingsinyourteam_14F1A/shared_code_style_thumb_1.jpg](http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/alternativedotnet/WindowsLiveWriter/SharingReSharpersettingsinyourteam_14F1A/shared_code_style_thumb_1.jpg)